# how to get dynamic id inside p tag or dynamic value of input type

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have added content by appending p tag with dynamic id under div live below:

```
$("#show_comments").append('<p id="'+ id +'">' + msg + '<input type="hidden" id="delcomment" value="'+id +'"> <input type="button" id="del_status" value="Delete">' + '</p><br/>'); id++;
```

In HTML format, it'll be

```
<p id="1">
test A
<input type="hidden" id="delcomment" value="1">
<input type="button" id="del_status" value="Delete">
</p>

<p id="2">
test B
<input type="hidden" id="delcomment" value="2">
<input type="button" id="del_status" value="Delete">
</p>
```

I tried to get either id value of p tag (that is 1 or 2 or etc) or value of input type hidden delcomment (that is 1 or 2 or etc) by pressing Delete button.

```
 $("#show_comments").on('click', '#del_status', function () { console.log($("#delcomment").val());
```

But every time it give first value of delcomment under div when I click "test C" to delete.
That is 1 (test A value) instead of 3 of "test C".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygMOl.png)

May I know how could I achieve to get id value of p tag (that is 1 or 2 or etc) or value of input type hidden delcomment (that is 1 or 2 or etc) by pressing Delete button.

Comment: You can't have two same ids on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can't have duplicate in `id`s, so change `id`s of the `input`s to classes like:

```js
$("#show_comments").on('click', '.del_status', function () { console.log($(this).closest('p').find('.delcomment').val())});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show_comments">
  <p id="1">
    test A
    <input type="hidden" class="delcomment" value="1">
    <input type="button" class="del_status" value="Delete">
    </p>
    <p id="2">
    test B
    <input type="hidden" class="delcomment" value="2">
    <input type="button" class="del_status" value="Delete">
    </p>
    
</div>
```

Now about your question, in `console.log($("#delcomment").val()` returns multiple elements, and it logs the value of first item. considering that you have changed `id`s to classes, change your code to:

```
$("#show_comments").on('click', '.del_status', function () { console.log($(this).closest('p').find('.delcomment').val())});
```

Now it will only get the element inside it's parent `p` element and not the whole `div`.